# Change div content in header, depending on page loaded in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a div, containing a phone number.

I then have multiple area pages from which the locations change.

How do I change the phone number in the header dependant on which area page has loaded and wether or not the page is an area page...

I would like one number for every page except for the area pages, which I would like individual numbers for...

How do I go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom template for those pages that displayed a particular section or use is_page();

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

Which can be used with either page ids or slugs;

```
if (is_page(42)) {
    // Show something specific to page 42.
}
```

You can see the page ID by clicking on the page in the Wordpress Pages admin menu, you can see the id in the url.

```
if (is_page('Contact')) {
    // This uses the slug, but of course the client might change that slug which will break the functionality
}
```

Comment: This is the solution I've been using, the problem is when I use is_page to add content to a page, the other data is still being displayed. Resulting in me having two lots of data (phone numbers) displayed rather than the one.

The only other option is to use is_page to add the individual phone number to the pages and then use another is_page with page ID's of every page of my site to include the other phone number, there must be a simpler solution.

Comment: I have solved this by using multiple conditional statements...thanks for your help! :)